# QuickBooks Online v3 - REST API and the SDK

Tags: php, api, curl, integration, quickbooks-online

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to properly proceed making calls using the Intuit QuickBooks Online API v3. I've looked at the API Explorer, and from my understanding, I can send and receive JSON.

They also provide information about the base URL, the entity, etc: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/Customer

So I'm wondering, am I supposed to be using the QuickBooks SDK that they mention to download? https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting

Or would I be able to utilize their API using something like cURL? I don't want to reinvent the wheel of course, but with all the information they provide and no reference to the SDK itself, that's where I started to get a little confused. They basically tell you how to make the calls, but don't reference the SDK in those documents.

Just to provide some extra information, I'm using PHP 5.5 and Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I'm wondering, am I supposed to be using the QuickBooks SDK that they mention to download?

If you want to, sure.

> Or would I be able to utilize their API using something like cURL?

Again, if you want to, sure. Just be aware that if you use cURL, you'll have to do some OAuth signing of your requests (see the OAuth spec) or find an OAuth lib too.

Here's another open-source alternative if you need something with more examples (disclaimer: I'm the author):

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

Examples:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/tree/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3